# Division Theorem/Half Remainder Version

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove the following Division Theorem/Half Remainder Version?

∀
  a
  ,
  b
  ∈
  
    Z
  
  ,
  b
  ≠
  0
  :
  ∃
  !
  q
  ,
  r
  ∈
  
    Z
  
  :
  a
  =
  q
  b
  +
  r
  ,
  −
  
    
      
        |
        b
        |
      /
      2
    
  
  ≤
  r
  <
  
    
      
        |
        b
        |
      /
      2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.**

- For uniqueness, use the fact that the only integral multiple of $b$  in $ [-\vert b\vert /2;\vert b\vert /2)$ is $0$.

  For existence:
- Assume that you proved the existence of $q$ and $r$  if $b>0$. How to deduce the existence when $b<0$ ?
- Assume that $b>0$. Write $a=q'b+r', 0\leq r' \leq \vert b\vert.$ If $b/2\leq r<b$, in which interval $r-b$ belongs to ?